# How to use pagination in Play framework

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, playframework

I am using angularJS, Play framework, Java and Mongo Db, Help me to implement Server side  Pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use limit() and skip() in MongoDB.

Example: I have Users collection.

```
db.getCollection('users').find({}).limit(10).skip(0)
```

You have to pass your URL with `?limit=10&offset=0` like `https://domain/api/users?limit=10&offset=0`

You have to use offset in skip().

limit() is for how many records you display in your page.. 
skip() is for records skip

Comment: thanks for answer, But i am excepting via play frame work implement server-side pagination, Can you help me

Comment: @Venunadh you would then decide how many elements you want per page, and for each page number you would get X elements back starting at record `X * page number` (maybe +/-1 depending on how you implement it).